# out of memory exceptions when using Telelrik controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, telerik

In the following code I have a commented out standard asp Datagrid view, and the Telerik RadGrid.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

On the c# side this is the code i have in the page_load

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection( ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SHBNdbConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
string query = "SELECT ProjectDesc,ProjectLoc,ProjectStatus FROM tblProjects INNER JOIN tblClients ON tblClients.ProjectID=tblProjects.ProjectID WHERE tblClients.ClientID='"+ id +"';";

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
{
    sda.SelectCommand = com;
    sda.Fill(dt);
    RadGrid1.DataSource = dt;
    RadGrid1.DataBind();
}

conn.Close();
```

Now the commented out part of the c# code works fine, If i run the website and open it it will display data in the standard Datagridview, but, when i do the same thing for the Telerik RadGrid (which contains the assembly reference in the html and the Bin folder with the dll) I get the following error:

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Exception of type `System.OutOfMemoryException` was thrown.

Why is this happening exclusively when i use the Telerik controls?

Comment: I think it is better to bind web controls to a datareader then a datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Telerik RadGrid stores its data in the page's ViewState, and if it gets significantly large, it can throw the `System.OutOfMemoryException` you're seeing.

Try to disable the ViewState storage in the RadGrid's settings by setting `EnableViewState="false"` like this:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
```

Check out [this page](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-viewstate-optimization.html) for more information on optimizing the ViewState for Telerik controls.